# Files included from the default SolrConfig

Tags: solr, lucene

I am trying to optimize solr.

The default solrConfig that comes with solr>collection1 has a lot of libs included I dont really need. Perhaps if someone could help we identifying the purpose. (I only import from DIH):

Please tell me whats in these:

```
contrib/extraction/lib
solr-cell-

contrib/clustering/lib
solr-clustering-

contrib/langid/lib/
solr-langid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

contrib/extraction/lib
solr-cell-*

These are [Solr Cell](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler) Libraries which integrates with Tika and helps you Index Rich documents e.g. Microsoft Word, Excel etc.

contrib/clustering/lib
solr-clustering-

[Solr clustering](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ClusteringComponent) is for the Clustering support integrated with Carrot.
Clustering would help you group documents, topic, entity extraction and much more.

contrib/langid/lib/
solr-langid

[Solr Language I](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageDetection)d for the Language detection. It adds the ability to detect the language of a document before indexing and then make appropriate decisions about analysis, etc.

Just exclude the jars if you are not using any of the above features and be sure you remove the mappings from the Solr configuration files as well.

Comment: I love the fact that your the only Solr guy on Stack :D Can you please tell me 1 thing: isnt Faceting also doing categorization? then why use clustering?

Comment: Clustering is more dynamic for e.g. like topic extraction for people or names or document clustering based on the content. Faceting is more static, based on the values you provide.